# How to get a website's console content via "web-request" [NPM PKG]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-package

I installed the web-request NPM package and want to get console messages from the website I chose to get. The problem was I didn't know how to.

```
  var result = await WebRequest.get('http://discordapp.com/app');
  var result2 = result.get.statusMessage();
  console.log(result2.content)
```

This is my code, it returns a TypeError that it cannot read statusMessage of undefined. I'm not really familiar with this NPM package and I wasn't able and unsure of how and where to get the documentation.

I use this website to get my package. This NPM package works in Javascript but is coded in TypeScript. I'm unsure if this affects me.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-request

Answer (score -1):

> Try this code:

```
 var result = await WebRequest.get('http://discordapp.com/app');
 var result2 = result.statusMessage();
 console.log(result2.content)
```

Comment: This results again in the same typeerror `TypeError: Cannot read property statusMessage of undefined`